# Format a date column not written in mmddyyyy format in R

Tags: r, date, format

I have a character column as "Date" but not written in proper mmddyyyy format.

```
Example: 

ID      Date
125     9282007
350     10152007
225     1112007
240     1052007
```

How can I format the "Date" column to proper mmddyyyy format using R.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `library(lubridate); mdy(dat$Date)`. Of course, I've read in your data frame as `dat`. If you want `mmddyyyy` format see `?format.Date`.

Comment: And what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with `dplyr` + `lubridate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = gsub("(\\d{2})(\\d{4}$)", "-\\1-\\2", Date),
         Date = format(mdy(Date), "%m-%d-%Y"))
```

**Result:**

```
   ID       Date
1 125 09-28-2007
2 350 10-15-2007
3 225 01-11-2007
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "ID      Date
                125     9282007
                350     10152007
                225     1112007", header = TRUE)
```

**Note:**

The format of your original `Date`'s is ambiguous since 1112007 could mean 11-1-2007 or 1-11-2007. In my solution, I assumed that days is always two digit, so 11-1-2007 would be have been coded as 11-01-2007. You should however investigate whether that is the case before converting.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I have found another data element (see the last data row in the table above) but I have to consider 10 as 10 but not 01. The script above converts last row in the table to 01. Is there as fix for that?

Comment: @user8848543 Well, there's no way of knowing whether 1052007 stands for 10-05-2007 or 01-05-2007 unless you explicitly specify that the month has to have two digits. But that doesn't seem like the case because you have 9282007. You'll have to make a decision on how to set a rule to take these into consideration.